# Generate Next Alphanumeric Code on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I need to create a consecutive sequence of varchar(5) (**always 5 chars only**) code starting from PREVIOUS code.

For example

*'00000', '00001', '00002'...'00009', '0000A', '0000B'...'0000Z', '00010','00011'...'ZZZZZ'.*

So if I have **@PREVIOUS_CODE** = *'00000'*, **@NEXT_CODE** will be *'00001'*.

If I have **@PREVIOUS_CODE** = *'00009'*, **@NEXT_CODE** will be *'0000A'*

If I have **@PREVIOUS_CODE** = *'0000Z'*, **@NEXT_CODE** will be *'00010'*

So I need something like that

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetNextCode]
@PREVIOUS_CODE VARCHAR(5) 
AS
DECLARE @NEXT_CODE VARCHAR(5) 

DO STUFF
...

SELECT @NEXT_CODE AS NEXT_CODE
GO
```

Any Help?

Comment: Since SO is not a "school-project-solving-comunity", please update your question to "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep an integer counter in the same table and convert it. I'm using the following SQL Server function in one of my applications:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAlphanumericCode]  
(  
 @number BIGINT,  
 @leadingzeroes INT = 0  
)  
RETURNS varchar(255)  
AS  
BEGIN  

   DECLARE @charPool varchar(36)  
   SET @charPool = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'  

   DECLARE @result varchar(255)  

   IF @number < 0  
      RETURN ''  

   IF @number = 0  
      SET @result = '0'  
   ELSE BEGIN
      SET @result = ''  

      WHILE (@number > 0)  
      BEGIN  
         SET @result = substring(@charPool, @number % 36 + 1, 1) + @result  
         SET @number = @number / 36 
      END  
   END  

   IF @leadingzeroes > 0 AND len(@result) < @leadingzeroes  
      SET @result = right(replicate('0', @leadingzeroes) + @result, @leadingzeroes)  

   RETURN @result  

END
```

It should be a trivial task to rewrite it as a stored procedure